# Dynamically Edit Material on GLTF Model in React-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, gltf, react-three-fiber

I'm attempting to dynamically change texture map values of a ".gltf" model in a simple react-three-fiber scene. If I'm understanding this correctly, you must add the texture files on a material and then add the material to the model? In my scenario, the texture files are baked into the ".gltf" file. I would like to change values such as the opacity of the alphaMap with jsx.

Here's my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-framework-3holn?file=/src/App.js

I know this is probably really simple, but I have not a clue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either do this:

```
<mesh geometry={...}>
  <meshStandardMaterial color={materials.Moon.color} transparent opacity={0.5} />
```

or this:

```
<mesh geometry={...} material={materials.Moon} material-transparent material-opacity={0.5} >
```

dash case can pierce as deep as you want, you can modify texture values as well:

```
<mesh ... material-map-flipY>
```

see: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/blob/master/markdown/api.md#piercing-into-nested-properties

Comment: It seems I'm doing something wrong. I added the "meshStandardMaterial" including the material to the color map. I also tried "MeshStandardMaterial."https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-framework-3holn?file=/src/Moon.js ; I am getting an Object.defineProperty error.

Comment: I also did the  "material-transparent material-opacity={0.5}" directly on the mesh; it worked, but it shows the silhouette of the topology of the sphere. It's almost as if the opacity values are different for each triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily manipulate the properties of the objects in your scene, regardless of whether the original one was baked into your GLTF file. For example, you can change the material's main texture like this *after* your GLTF has loaded:

```
var texLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var newTexture = texLoader.load("my/new/texture.jpg");
object.material.map = newTexture;
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip, but im looking to change the values of maps. Is there a way to edit the values of the maps specifically? Here's an example of map displacement values being changed on mouse drag of cursor https://cineshader.com/ ; i was wondering if this was possible with jsx.

Comment: The Cineshader demo uses custom shaders. I guess you could [try learning `GLSL` and custom shader creation](https://thebookofshaders.com/) to copy that behavior. Alternatively, [here's an example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_texture_canvas) of a dynamically created texture using a 2D `<canvas>` context. Just draw on the upper-right square, and you'll see it on the cube.

Comment: Thank you! This is a perfect example to learn from.